# "Attendant with" vs. "attendant to" vs. "attendant of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adjectives, collocation

Can the adjective *attendant* be used with the prepositions *with, to,* or *of*, and, if so, which is preferable?

For example, I could say, "This manual describes the operation of the product and its attendant risks," but could I also say, "This manual describes risks that are attendant with the operation of the product"?

Comment: The "standard" preposition here is *risks that are attendant **on** operation of the product*, but it's a somewhat starchy/dated usage. You'd be better sticking with the first version. Personally, I'd change "attendant" to "associated", but "attendant risks" is relatively well established set phrasing for such contexts.

Comment: The OED does not really have an example of such modern usage as *risks attendant on use of dangerous equipment*. The nearest I could find was: 
*1869   J. T. Coleridge Mem. J. Keble iv. 65   Melancholy is a common attendant on poetic genius.* The more I think about it 'on' does appear to be the 'standard' preposition. But 'associated with' does not have quite the same meaning, or does it?

Comment: @WS2 I think "associated" and "attendant" are definitely synonymous, but, as with most synonyms, each word carries its own connotation vis-à-vis the spectrum of their related definitions.

Comment: Instead of “risks that are attendant with the operation of the product” I'd write “risks concomitant with operation of the product”.  Note,  *attendant* is among synonyms of *[concomitant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concomitant#Adjective)*.

Comment: @jwpat7 -- Ha, it's funny, when I was searching for the right word, I actually started with concomitant but somehow got hung up on attendant.  I like concomitant, but my question is still about "attendant" in a theoretical sense.

Answer (score 1):

> risks attendant with [something]

The risks are commonly associated with [something].  Doing [something] might create those risks, or perhaps there's some other reason for them.  For example, perhaps [something] is a technique to deal with a particular problem, and that problem creates the risks.

> risks attendant to [something]

The risks directly result from [something].  [Something] causes them.

> risks attendant of [something]

I've not heard this variation often.  I would not use it in my own writing.

> risks attendant on [something]

Ditto.

Comment: Could you please provide references for this?  I can't find any resources that *actually say* you can use the word with a preposition.

Comment: I'd use 'attendant to', if a formal register was a sensible option, but the definition can be  broader: 'associated with'. An internet example: '... their thoughts and feelings attendant to the events described.' [[Clinical Child and Family Psychology Review; Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/the+attendants+to+the+event)] Also 'the nonmoral facts attendant to the situation' [[CORE](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/131199727.pdf)]

Answer (score 0):

I would identify "attendant on" as the proper form, though it [appears](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attendant%20on%2C%20attendant%20with%2C%20attendant%20to%2C%20attendant%20of&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cattendant%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Battendant%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAttendant%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cattendant%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Battendant%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAttendant%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cattendant%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Battendant%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAttendant%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cattendant%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Battendant%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAttendant%20of%3B%2Cc0) that neither that nor any of the options which the question identifies is much used these days. But solicitors still regularly start their attendance notes, "Attending on [name of client]..."

Answer (score 0):

The 1993 edition of the Larousse French-English, English-French Dictionary gives examples only with 'on'. I personally would opt for 'to' — but only if I had to use such a construction and word.